# java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10008 nor current process has android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS

Tags: android, security

When I want to run a child thread in a service, the thread throws the below exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10008 nor current process has android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS

Here is my code (part of `Thread` implementation):

```
try {
    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    mSystemFacade.getActiveNetworkInfo(mInfo.mUid);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: read your exception carefully

Comment: as described in the API: `Not for use by third-party applications.` . So, no matter what you are doing, you can´t use this permission. only if you have root access for your app.... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS